# I have a set of N deformed circles made of lines. How to generate similar circle?

Tags: machine-learning, geometry

I have a set of N deformed circles made of lines. Each circle can have difrent amount of lines defining it. They are deformed in difrent manner but one could see the similarities between them. How to generate a new similar circle having desired lines count K - which ML algorithms it is better to look into?

Comment: Please add some examples of input and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

A circle that pass **near** of given vertices (in general case, it isn't possible to pass through all vertices) can be estimated with some maths. For example see [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/sup962/gander.pdf)

An aproximation can be achieved by:

- Get the coordinates of the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points),
  two simple (x,y) average.
- The radius can be estimated by the average of the distances from vertices to the centroid.